# Activity notifications of groups my page joins are turned off, but why do I still get them?

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-groups, facebook-notifications

I join several groups as page, and make sure that the notifications of group activities are turned off, but I still get them. Why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://www.facebook.com/pg/YOUR_PAGE/groups/ there will be another button to hide notification:

[image]

However not all the groups are shown in this list, and not always a group has this option. I don't know why